# Prestashop 1.7: How to set CMS page as homepage

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

Can anyone please help me with is question here.  I want to set a CMS page as homepage in prestashop 1.7 and still able to keep the old default Prestashop homepage as my Shop button link in menu still?

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to make a redirection, because on the Prestashop backend you cannot do that easely and it could harm your website. You can also build your own Html and integrate it on the homepage via a module.

But best seems to be with a redirection :

- Your server uses apache, just add this line to the .htaccess :
  Redirect 301 /retiredpage.html /newpage.html
- Your server uses nginx, add this line to your configuration : rewrite ^/retiredpage.html$ /newpage.html permanent;
- You don't know and you don't want that ? Just use a redirection module, there are many on Prestashop Addons.

Comment: The advantage of this solution is I do not have to hack code, but how to display the original home page?

Answer (score 0):

On the index.php page at the root of the site, replace the code with that:

```
require(dirname(__FILE__).'/config/config.inc.php');
if(Tools::getValue('home')) {
    Dispatcher::getInstance()->dispatch();
} else {
    $link = new Link();
    Tools::redirect($link->getCMSLink(ID_PAGE_CMS));
}
```

Then if you go on the homepage you will be redirected to the CMS page for which you have indicated the link, to go via the menu on the real home page, add? Home at the end of the url of your website www.yourwebsite.tld? home

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the redirection doesn't work, I get 'The page isn’t redirecting properly' in the browser. I found an other solution, I added this in /controllers/front/indexController.php :      `if (!$_GET['page'] == 'shop')
   Tools::redirect('contact');` When I put page=shop in the url, I get the original home page